# PHP Load content (picture) of URL from another URL (json)

Tags: php, json, curl

im trying to do this:
load http://example.com/nickname/picture (nickname is loaded as a var in the url you visit, that´s working)
decode to json
the site is this

```
{
"picture": "https://example.com/hf8329yrh8oq.jpg"
}
```

load the picture
what i tried:

```
function curlGet($url)
   {
   $crl = curl_init();
   $timeout = 5;
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
   $status = curl_exec($crl);
   curl_close($crl);
   return $status;
   }
$profPicCurl = curlGet('https://example.com/'.urlencode($_GET['nickname']).'/picture')
$profPic = json_decode($profPicCurl,true);
echo file_get_contents($profPic.["picture"]);
```

i know I didn´t handle errors and stuff in this script, but i want it to work with a real image first before.

so the mean question: how to display and image from a decoded json site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need `curl`?
You can also replace `file_get_contents` with `curlGet` in my code

```
<?php
  $profPic  = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/'.urlencode( $_GET['nickname'] ).'/picture' ) );
  if ( $profPic ) { // is a valid json object
    if ( isset( $profPic->picture ) ) { // profile picture exists
      $profPic  = $profPic->picture;
      $extension  = strtolower( pathinfo( $profPic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ); // get the image extension
      $content  = file_get_contents( $profPic ); // get content of image
      if ( $content ) {
        header( "Content-type: image/".$extension ); // set mime type
        echo $content; // output the content
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
  echo "File not found"; // there is some errors :\
?>
```

Comment: do you really need curl -- well, looks like a no. thanks! you really helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUserImage($nick, $imgUrl = false) {
        $jsonString = file_get_contents("http://example.com/".$nickname."/picture");
        $json = json_decode($jsonString);
        if ($imgUrl){
            return $json->picture;
        } else {
            return file_get_contents($json->picture);
        }
};
```

Then to use

```
<?php
header("Content_Type: image/jpeg");
echo getUserImage("quagmire");
```

or

```
<img src="<?= getUrlImage("quagmire", true) ?>"/>
```